# Remove selection from ListView element in UI Toolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, ui-toolkit

When I drag the elements inside the ListView component, in the new UI Toolkit system, the element selected get white background but I want it to be transparent.

I just want to drag the elements like a list but without changing the elements background color.
[image]

I've tried a lot of things with the new API but could not figure it out.
I tried change the element background, disable listview general properties, research in google but nothing

I would like if you guys can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in your USS file. It will rewrite the built-in properties

```
.unity-list-view__item {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```